# Post title links appear to be broken

Tags: posts

I am troubleshooting for a friend and have very little Wordpress experience so apologies in advance.

I am wondering where to look to track down an issue that has cropped up with post teasers. Basically when looking at a category listing page or even a search results page the teasers are output normally except for the link that is added to the post title. Normally the link would be built from the category plus the post title, however something has caused the links to output stopping at the category level and omitting the post title, thus breaking the links for all post teasers.

```
Should be:

https://www.example.com/[category]/[post-title]

Output currently:

https://www.exampe.com/[category]
```

Any help or pointers about where to look to try to track down the source of the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, turn off any plugins and test again. Second, try a default theme like 'twentyfifteen'. Third, see files inside the `/template-parts`, also `category.php`, `taxonomy.php` in the theme root. Nobody knows how your theme is organized, all paranormalists are on holidays now. A link or theme name could help with no warranty it helps.

Comment: Try changing the permalink structure under Settings, then change it back to what you want it to be.